# Check a check box is checked or not using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to check a checkbox is checked or not using jquery. When click  on the check box, check the checkbox is checked or not using jquery. My  code is   given below.

```
   <script>
   function check(id)
    {
     if($("#id:checked").length == 1)
      {
        alert("cheked");
      }
    }
   </script>


     Html
     $i=1;
     <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" 
     id="one<?php echo $i; ?>"  onclick="check(one<?php echo $i; ?>)"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the element reference to the method

```
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="one<?php echo $i; ?>"  onclick="check(this)"/>
```

then check the checked property value

```
function check(el) {
    if (el.checked) {
        alert("cheked");
    }
}
```

Note: Since you are using jQuery, instead of using inline event handlers try to use jQuery event handlers

---

In your script the problem is, `id` is a variable holding the actual `id` so you need to use string concatenation

```
function check(id) {
    if ($("#" + id + ":checked").length == 1) {
        alert("cheked");
    }
}
```

Also since the `id` is a string, it has to be enclosed in a `''` in the click handler call

```
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="one<?php echo $i; ?>"  onclick="check('one<?php echo $i; ?>')"/>
```

Comment: Can you say ,how check  a check box with id?

Comment: i want the id of check box in check function.

Comment: @vanikk `$('#' + id).prop('checked', true)`